# Is there a reason why the delete[]p; will not delete my array values?

Tags: c++, memory, new-operator, delete-operator

I am currently using C++ on VScode with C/C++ and CodeRunner application. For some reason, even though adding the `delete[]p` in my code, the values in the following array remain there. Can someone please help?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int *p;
    p = new int[2];
    p[0] = 10;
    p[1] = 20;
    delete[]p;
    cout<< "Value in P[0] before "<<p[0]<<endl;
    cout<< "Value in P[1] before "<<p[1]<<endl;

    return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
Value in P[0] before 10
Value in P[1] before 20
```

Shouldn't the value of `P[0]` and `P[1]` be different after we use the `delete[]p` constructor, as we are deallocating the memory from the heap?

Am I missing something in my C++ program to be able to run this?

Comment: Accessing elements in an array after it's been deleted is **undefined behavior**.

Comment: Because the C++ standard neither requires, nor forbids, the data in the array to be overwritten.  By dereferencing `p` (i.e. accessing `p[0]` and `p[1]`) your program has undefined behaviour, so any outcome is permitted and an implementation (e.g. your compiler and library) can do anything it likes (e.g. retrieve values array that were there before, or reformat your hard drive) and still be correct. If you want memory overwritten, then overwrite that memory BEFORE doing `delete [] p` (some implementations might overwrite it again, but some won't) and don't access it after doing `delete [] p`.

Comment: But the most likely explanation is that the in-process memory manager of the C/C++ runtime has claimed the memory back, but hasn't reallocated it before your subsequent `cout` statements . Hence, the memory address still exists and has the same contents.  But that behavior could change based on any number of conditions. Often in debug builds, the compiler will insert some special bytes to make it easier to recognize deleted memory being accessed. But that's not standard either.

Comment: [Here is a nice answer for a similar, but different situation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6445794/631266) The details are different, but the analogy works just as well here.

Comment: Accessing contents of a deleted objects [makes demons fly out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). These are very nasty, very evil demons. They can make you believe that the data is still there. But it's not. If you don't want to deal with nasal demons, don't ever access anything that's been deleted.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik   Demons are only created by some systems.   Most computers don't have the hardware, firmware, or wetware support.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of your program is undefined as you're using the expressions `p[0]` and `p[1]` after using `delete[]p;`.

Undefined behavior means [anything can happen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72395390/19414420), don't rely on the output of a program that has UB.

Comment: This is correct, but doesn't really *explain* what's going on.