# Accessing works even after the using delete keyword

Tags: c++, c++11

This might be a very trivial question but why am I still able to access the values from the array(which was dynamically allocated) even after using the `delete` keyword.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    #ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
        freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
        freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
        freopen("error.txt","w",stderr);
    #endif

    int *arr = new int[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        arr[i] = i+1;

    }

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    delete[] arr;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){

        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

What i know is that using the `delete` keyword frees the memory which was allocated.

I am pretty new to C++. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Undefined behavior, anything can happen. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72395390/12002570) for example.

Comment: @pptaszni so this is not a concept it is just some undefined behaviour?

Comment: Undefined behavior means anything could happen as also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72395390/12002570)

Comment: When you delete `arr` the memory allocated to the array doesn't cease to exist its just marked as available for re-use, therefore there is a chance (especially just after `delete` in a single threaded program) that the array will continue to be accessible. This is completely undefined behaviour though, it might "work" one time you run the program but crash the next

Comment: @AlanBirtles this is probably a better explanation. I thought that using `delete` frees the memory and memory would not be accessible.

Comment: ***I thought that using delete frees the memory and memory would not be accessible***The reason for this behavior is your c++ memory management typically allocates blocks of memory from your OS in pages. These pages are usually a few KB. Perhaps something else is in the page so the whole page can't be given back to the OS. Also even if that was not the case your c++ memory  management may not give the memory back immediately to your OS  because this OS operation is time consuming and perhaps your application will soon allocate another memory block..